# Center My Search Box

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment, center

I'm trying to align my search box to always be at the center of the page on my WordPress page.

You can see what I'm talking about at http://dev.replacementdustcollectorfilter.com/.

I put the box input box in it's own div & class `<div class="search-form-box">`, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` to your `#search` div. This assigns a left and right margin of `auto`, which will center the div.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114549/2126792) and the [docs at w3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp).